# programming custom blendmode for Adobe Photoshop (or After Effects)

Tags: plugins, adobe, blend

What's the easiest way to create a custom blendmode for Adobe Photoshop?

I want to be able to blend two images together according to rules that can't be created by combining existing blendmodes

(i.e. the blendresult shall be dst = backLayer + (frontlayer*2-1) which can't be achieved by applying linear dodge twice and then subtracting a white layer since clamping will occur - and when working in a 32bit workspace, the blendmodes will not behave as expected anymore)

I tried to program pbk kernels in PixelBender, but Photoshop's PixelBender doesn't seem to support pbk kernels that take more than one image as input (can work only as filter on a single image).

What's the most straight forward way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following technique works:
http://www.photoshopgurus.com/forum/general-photoshop-board/25925-custom-blending-modes-possible.html